# JSF PrimeFaces Layout

Tags: maven, jsf-2, primefaces

I m a beginner using JSF and PrimesFaces, i took an example on the official web site :"http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutFull.jsf" , unfortunately the layout doesn't appears.

Here the result --->

Top
North unit content.
Bottom
South unit content.
Left
West unit content.
Right
Right unit content.
This fullPage layout consists of five different layoutUnits which are resizable and closable by default.

I think my project isn't well configured.
Here is my POM:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
<groupId>com.otv</groupId>
<artifactId>OTV_JSF_PrimeFaces</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>OTV_JSF_PrimeFaces Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <!-- JSF library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.faces</groupId> <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId> 
    <version>1.2_15</version> </dependency> -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Log4j library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Any body can help ? Thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add repository to your pom.xml file; Read downloading with maven section http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html

then try with simple button if you see it or not;

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit"/>
```